# Debug Visual Studio native test project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Native Test Project for testing my C++ project.
Is there any way how to see order of tests execution when debugging tests? Or any detailed debugging information?

I would like to use Visual Studio online for continuous integration, but there is some issue with my tests. It always crashes on VSO server. I tried to run it manually from console on my computer and it works fine. But when I run it in debug mode in Visual Studio on my local machine, there are some random failures with test runner. It throws exception

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\TE.ProcessHost.Managed.exe'.
>
> RuntimeCallableWrapper is disconnected from its resources
>
> HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)

problem is this exception is quite random and I think it depends on tests execution order. When I run all tests one-by-one, it is fine, no exception is thrown. I'm really desperate how to debug it :(

Comment: I am seeing the same problem but in a C# solution in VS2015 with update 1.

Comment: Same problem here - can't deug any C++ native test project, VS2015 Update 2.